# Cytoscape height canvas fixed to 0

Tags: css, cytoscape.js

I'm using cytoscape.js and when I try to initialize it, I found the canvas height to 0. I don't understand why.

This is my js :

```
var cy = cytoscape({container: document.getElementById("mapping")});

cy.add([
        {group: "nodes", data: {id: "n0"}, position: {x:0, y:0}},
        {group: "nodes", data: {id: "n1"}, position: {x:100, y:50}},
        {group: "edges", data: {id: "e0", source: "n0", target: "n1"}}
]);
console.log(cy.container());
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/109256/) where you can see the "height":0px in log and nothing in rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you initialize cytoscape with static data, consider doing it like the documentation shows:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
container: document.getElementById('cy'), // container to render in
  elements: [ // list of graph elements to start with
    { // node a
      data: { id: 'a' }
    },
    { // node b
      data: { id: 'b' }
    },
    { // edge ab
      data: { id: 'ab', source: 'a', target: 'b' }
    }
  ],
  style: [ // the stylesheet for the graph
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'background-color': '#666',
        'label': 'data(id)'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'width': 3,
        'line-color': '#ccc',
        'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ],
  layout: {                   /!!!
    name: 'grid',
    rows: 1
  }
});
```

you dont specify a layout in your sample code, i rarely do it like that, i simply add the nodes/edges and call the layout algorithm i want, the rest of your code seems ok, did you  include all scripts and css files for cytoscape?

Comment: You're right, cytoscape container has to be initialized (in the css)(in my case) with fixed height and width. Then, you can implement an algorithm to make canvas responsive "on page resize".